# FilteringSelect in mvc

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, dojo

I want to create an autocomplete input field so the user starts typing and in a drop down it will show the possible values. The data i will get from the database. Something with a dynamic store... How can i call my Methode from the controller?

I got following JS function:

```
searchNames:function()
     {
         var jsonStore = new JsonRest({
            url: config.rootContext + '/link/to/controllerMethod'
         });
         var memoryStore = new Memory();
         var myStore = new Cache(jsonStore, memoryStore);


        var fs = new FilteringSelect({
             id:  dijit.byId("serviceSelect"),
             store : memoryStore,
         });
         debugger;
         when(myStore.query({id:""})),
             function (items, request)
             {
                var val = "";
                if(items.length>0) val = items[0].id;
                 fs.set('value', val);
             }
     },
```

And my widget contains:

```
<td><select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" id="serviceSelect" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:searchNames"></select></td>
```

Thanks for inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FilteringSelect` widget already does this for you, so all you need to do is set store on it and it should work out of the box!

Since you already have the `data-dojo-type` attribute set in the HTML, you don't need to create another `FilteringSelect` in your JS code:

```
var jsonStore = new JsonRest({
  url: config.rootContext + '/link/to/controllerMethod'
});
var memoryStore = new Memory();
var myStore = new Cache(jsonStore, memoryStore);

var selectWidget = registry.byId('serviceSelect'); // registry refers to dijit/registry
selectWidget.set('store', myStore);
```

The HTML should look like this:

```
<td><select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" id="serviceSelect"></select></td>
```

Comment: Thank ysou. Did i have to put this code in the constructor (or something smilar) or did i have to add some onChange method?

Comment: this code should go in the "controller" for you page - if it's another parent widget, you should put in the "postCreate" or if it's just some code that executes onDocumentReady, you can also put it there